# Why should use warnings; go last?

Tags: perl, warnings

I vaguely recall that the `warnings` pragma should go last in the list of us modules being loaded with `use`.  I also vaguely remember that it has something to do with modules registering their own warning categories, but I can't reproduce any problems.  Can someone point to a relevant article or show an example where the placement of the `warnings` pragma makes a difference?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This may be what you're referring to. Either way it's something to be aware of and I'm submitting it as a bug.  **Edit** The [bug](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=128765) was fixed in v5.27.6.

#### My/Warnings.pm

```perl
package My::Warnings;

use warnings::register;

sub test {
    warnings::warnif 'This is my warning';
}

1;
```

#### main.pl

```perl
use strict;
use feature 'switch';

use warnings 'all';

use My::Warnings;

print undef;

given (1) { }

My::Warnings::test();
```

As expected, this will output

```
given is experimental at E:\Perl\source\main.pl line 10.
Use of uninitialized value in print at E:\Perl\source\main.pl line 8.
This is my warning at E:\Perl\source\main.pl line 12.
```

However, if *any* warnings category is disabled, it will also disable the custom category. Like this

```perl
use strict;
use feature 'switch';

use warnings 'all';
no warnings 'experimental';

use My::Warnings;

print undef;

given (1) { }

My::Warnings::test();
```

This outputs just

```
Use of uninitialized value in print at E:\Perl\source\main.pl line 9.
```

and it seems to be necessary to enable warnings *after* the `use My::Warnings` to get them to perform

```perl
use strict;
use feature 'switch';

use My::Warnings;

use warnings 'all';
no warnings 'experimental';

print undef;

given (1) { }

My::Warnings::test();
```

Produces

```
Use of uninitialized value in print at E:\Perl\source\main.pl line 9.
This is my warning at E:\Perl\source\main.pl line 13.
```

---

#### Update

What's more, reenabling the category that switched off the custom warnings leaves them disabled

Something like this

```
use strict;
use feature 'switch';

use warnings 'all';
no warnings 'experimental';
use warnings 'experimental';

use My::Warnings;

print undef;

given (1) { }

My::Warnings::test();
```

prints just

```
given is experimental at E:\Perl\source\main.pl line 12.
Use of uninitialized value in print at E:\Perl\source\main.pl line 10.
```

Comment: [Here's my bug report](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=128765). I've yet to respond. ***Father Chrysostomos*** says *"Some time ago I suspected we had a problem like this"*. His description of the underlying code is illuminating.